# Why 2 + 1 & 0 result is 0?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In VC2008, I typed this code:

```
int a = 2 + 1 & 0;
```

and this expression's result is
a = 0

Why the result is 0 but not 2?

Comment: search Operator precedence in C/C++.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because the `&` operator [is evaluated after](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) the `+` operator and `3 & 0` equals `0`.

Of course you can place braces around the expressions to change the evaluation order. E.g:

```
int a = 2 + (1 & 0);
/* a == 2 */
```

Answer (score 5):

The `+` has greater precedence than the `&`. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) is a complete table of operator precedence.